# Why am I receiving an error while deploying my Node.js app using MongoDB and Mongoose in Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, deployment

I'm receiving this error while trying to deploy my app to render. It works perfectly on my computer. I do not know what I should do, and that is a rare scenario, so please help me.

[image]

I tried downgrading MongoDB and Moongose, and I've also tried to upgrade them, and so much more, but NOTHING WORKS.

Comment: what is the node version [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing#browser_compatibility) requires node14 or above

Comment: Oh, thank you for your replay. let me check. I think that could be the problem.

Comment: i see in the logs it is node 10.24.1

Comment: When I first time uploaded the code, the package.json had the engine set to NodeJS V 10.x.x. because it's an older app that I upgraded and wanted to showcase. I did remove it, but Render is using cache so it always used the old cached engine. I deleted the project, and set the engine inside of the package.json file to 14.x.x. and it worked. Thank you for putting me on the right path. The app is live now, and all the kudos go to you, my friend.

Comment: awesome! glad you managed to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`??` is the nullish coalesce operator that is only supported in Node.js 14 and above. From the log you shared you're using Node.js 10.24.1.

By default, Render should use Node.js 14.17.0, so you're probably explicitly specifying this old version either in the `NODE_VERSION` environment variable, in a `.node_version` file or in an `engines` entry in your `package.json` - see the details in [Render's Specifying a Node Version](https://render.com/docs/node-version) help topic.

You should find where you're setting this version and update it to something more modern (at least 14.0.0).

Comment: When I first time uploaded the code, the package.json had the engine set to NodeJS V 10.x.x. because it's an older app that I upgraded and wanted to showcase. I did remove it, but Render is using cache so it always used the old cached engine. I deleted the project, and set the engine inside of the package.json file to 14.x.x. and it worked. Thank you for putting me on the right path. The app is live now, and all the kudos go to you, my friend.