# Problem moving typescript to an earlier version

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have been developing a `node.js` server app using `node 19.5`. Today I wanted to check that it would run OK on the (remote) production server, which is shared.
Unfortunately I discovered that the remote server has `node 12.22.11` installed. (I asked for it to be upgraded but they say that would upset existing users).

I have checked all the npm packages used, and all but 2 are OK with node 12.

But I'm having problems downgrading `tsx` to ver 3.14.0 (it was 4.x) and `typescript` to version 4.7.2 (it was 5.x).

In my npm list for `tsx` I am getting

```
+-- tsx@3.14.0
| +-- esbuild@0.18.20
| | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @esbuild/android-arm@0.18.20
| | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @esbuild/android-arm64@0.18.20
| | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @esbuild/android-x64@0.18.20
| | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.18.20
```

and I don't know if I need to be concerned about these.
But more importantly, perhaps, I cannot get `tsc` to run at all:

```
PS C:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ridehub-server> tsc
C:\Users\quilk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:93
  for (let i = startIndex ?? 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\quilk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I receiving an error while deploying my Node.js app using MongoDB and Mongoose in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76400029/why-am-i-receiving-an-error-while-deploying-my-node-js-app-using-mongodb-and-mon) TL;DR: [The nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) was not supported until Node 14; thus Node 12 does not implement this functionality. Your dependencies are simply not compatible with this version of Node.

Comment: Do you need TypeScript to work on the production server? You could compile your TypeScript to JavaScript on a dev or staging machine, then upload the result to production. TypeScript can even compile the nullish coalescing to something that Node v12 would support (since it doesn't support nullish coalescing).

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question as asked, but I believe it's important to note that **Node 12** (as of this writing) **has not received any security updates for over a year** since its LTS period expired 30 Apr 2022. This should go without saying, but **Node 12 should not be running on any production server anywhere** if you care even one iota about the application it's running or the data & infrastructure behind the application - doing so is a very bad idea and creates severe & completely unnecessary risks. Node 19 is also EOL and hasn't received any updates since 1 Jun '23.

Comment: @esqew thank you it sounds like I need to argue a bit more with my service provider!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, I guess I don't need `tsc` for the production server - and `tsx` is only used for debugging. But can you explain how to compile to avoid the `??` issue?

Comment: @quilkin - Set your `target` in `tsconfig.json` to something appropriate for Node v12, which will be something like `"es2015"` (aka `"es6"`) but check the docs, you might be able to push it to `es2016` or thereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows a null coalescing operator (`??`) in the `typescript` package's `tsc.js` file. The `??` operator is not supported in Node 12; you need at least Node 14.0.

That said, `typescript` only dropped Node 12 support in version 5.1 ([#53291](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53291)). Before that, I don't see the `??` operator used in `tsc.js`. So I believe the issue is that you didn't actually get the downgraded TypeScript version.

Try removing the `typescript` package and then re-adding version 5.0.x like so:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript@">=5.0.3 <5.1.0"
```